# How to show the reorder controls in UITableView with delete buttons

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I read the documentation about how to manage deletion and reordering of rows in a UITableView. I created the edit button and I'm able to delete rows. I would like the user to be able to reorder the rows as well. It seems simple, but I can't understand how to tell the cells that they can be moved.

To tell the rows they can be deleted I use the editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath, but how do I tell the cell it can also be moved and where do I set the showsReorderControl? I tried to place in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but nothing is shown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to say that rows can be moved:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}
```

and implement this delegate to update your data source:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
```

See [Managing the Reordering of Rows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) of [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/)

Comment: That's the documentation I'm reading. I already implemented that method exactly that way. But still I can't move anything. I can just delete the rows.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just noticed it is mandatory to implement moveRowAtIndexPath. I thought it was only necessary to modify the data source. Thanks!

Comment: Note to the unwary: you shouldn't call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` or `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` from the `moveRowAtIndexPath:` callback.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I have implemented all the required UITableViewDelegate methods as mentioned in the Apple document and in the answers here, but still cannot see the reorder control. Eventually I found out it's because I overrode the layoutSubviews method without calling the super's default implementation. After I added the [super layoutSubviews], my reorder control finally appears.

The reason why we need to call [super layoutSubviews] is because when we toggle the table's editing property it would call the cell's layoutSubviews method, and the system provided controls such as the reorder control is displayed within UITableViewCell's default layoutSubviews method. Once you realize this you can also modify your layoutSubviews implementation to change the appearance of your cell depending on whether it is being edited or not to make it less clumsy when the reorder control appears.

So here is a checklist for the row reordering:

1. make sure the delegate methods tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath and tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath are implemented
2. make sure the tableView's editing property is set to YES
3. If you have a custom UITableViewCell, make sure you call 
   [super layoutSubviews] if you override this method

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @benoit answer above. If your model happens to be a mutable array, something like this would suffice for the tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    id objectToMove = [_objects objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [_objects insertObject:objectToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];    
    [tableView reloadData];
    [self saveObjects];  // A method of your own to make new positions persistent
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this  . . .this will handle arranging and updating of cell in case of simple tableview

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
     [tableData insertObject: [tableData objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row] atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
     [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row + 1)];
}
```